The value of Power State Property is not match HID Report Descriptor
I can found a lot HID sensor's report descriptor contain below Power State property.
    HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_REPORTING_STATE,
    HID_LOGICAL_MIN(0),
    HID_LOGICAL_MAX(5),
    HID_REPORT_SIZE(8),
    HID_REPORT_COUNT(1),
    HID_COLLECTION(HID_COLLECTION_LOGICAL),
    HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_REPORTING_STATE_NO_EVENTS_SEL,
    HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_REPORTING_STATE_ALL_EVENTS_SEL,
    HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_REPORTING_STATE_THRESHOLD_EVENTS_SEL,
    HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_REPORTING_STATE_NO_EVENTS_WAKE_SEL,
    HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_REPORTING_STATE_ALL_EVENTS_WAKE_SEL,
    HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_REPORTING_STATE_THRESHOLD_EVENTS_WAKE_SEL,
    HID_FEATURE(HID_DATA | HID_ARRAY | HID_ABSOLUTE),
    HID_COLLECTION_END,

But, also, we can see the enum values defined (from document https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/9/e/09e57656-4368-4c44-8f18-0b6b285ec10a/hid-sensors-usages.docx)
//begin power state enums
#define HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_POWER_STATE_UNDEFINED_ENUM                            0x01 // Enum
#define HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_POWER_STATE_D0_FULL_POWER_ENUM                        0x02 // Enum
#define HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_POWER_STATE_D1_LOW_POWER_ENUM                         0x03 // Enum
#define HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_POWER_STATE_D2_STANDBY_WITH_WAKE_ENUM                 0x04 // Enum
#define HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_POWER_STATE_D3_SLEEP_WITH_WAKE_ENUM                   0x05 // Enum
#define HID_USAGE_SENSOR_PROPERTY_POWER_STATE_D4_POWER_OFF_ENUM                         0x06 // Enum
//end power state enums

It is start from 1 and the max value is 6, it is not match to report descriptor (0~5).
Why is it work?
Example: https://github.com/visakhanc/vusb_projects/blob/0fcdc978affc3d1f897cb348eee26e0073353840/hid-gyroscope/main.c#L239

Your report descriptor snippet is for reporting state, but your question is about power state. Could you edit your question to clarify?

But this property is contained and declared in the report descriptor. What title do you think is more suitable?

This seems like a bug in the report descriptor. Typically, a HID_ARRAY is used when you have a large number of possible values but only need to communicate a small number of values per report. For example, a keyboard input report uses an array to hold up to 6 keyboard usages representing pressed keys. Unused slots in the array are filled with an out-of-bounds value, typically zero. However, it is not uncommon for devices to mistakenly include the out-of-bounds value in the logical bounds.
In this case the device appears to be treating zero as an out-of-bounds value, so the first in-bounds value is 1.

But in most real cases, the property is defined with N enums and declared with a logical maximum of N-1. I found that many properties exhibit this behavior, not just PowerState. That really confuses me. What is the standard? I thought it will be 0 ~ N, but usually it is not.

The HID spec says the logical minimum/maximum define which values are in range, and an out-of-range value in an array item signifies "no controls asserted". But in the appendix, the spec gives a sample keyboard report descriptor that includes zero in the logical range. In practice I think there's an implicit assumption that zero is always an out-of-range array value even when zero is included in the logical range.
